# Trouble with ToR proxy

Tags: configuration, help, proxy, tor-browser-bundle

My college blocks basic websites such as Facebook and Skype. While I can manage Facebook with my mobile data, in order to talk to my family, Skype is too expensive on data.

The college WiFi uses a local HTTPS proxy. I can browse the blocked websites using the Tor browser, but is there a way to route all traffic of the computer so that is becomes uncensored. I realize this is pretty easy to do if the WiFi didn't run a local proxy but since it does, can anyone give a solution. Is it even possible? Also anonymity is not the criteria since I'm sure our college will not double check.

Comment: Have you tried tails? If not, could you explain your problem a bit more. Currently it is quite hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. What I want to achieve is to tunnel my whole device (Windows 10) and not just the browser. The reason is that my college uses a web filter (WEBCAT). I've tried VPNs like HotSpot Shield etc but they do not work as my college network has a proxy set up and apparantly the VPNs fail to connect through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full tunnel is achieved by a routing box: use a raspberry pi with linux on it - and utilize a TransPort functionality with IPTables. It will work. With a blocking proxies a pluggable transport like Obfs3/4 and Meek are considerable. Feel free to ask further questions : routing boxes are my speciality

Answer (score 0):

(Posting this as a *partial* answer since I cannot comment yet..)

You may save on your mobile data if you use their .onion address to connect to Facebook via your desktop, which I believe is: **facebookcorewwwi.onion** (you want to triple-check this, but source is [there](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/facebook-hidden-services-and-https-certs)).

Comment: That would certainly help up to a certain extent.. But I also need some kinda solution to the problem instead of avoiding it.. in the meanwhile I will o as you said :)

Answer (score 0):

Tor supports use of proxies to connect into the Tor network. Specifically, you can provide an [`HTTPSProxy`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HTTPSProxy) line and an [`HTTPSProxyAuthenticator`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#HTTPSProxyAuthenticator) to set any login credentials that may be required to use the proxy.

If you're using Tor Browser, this can be configured without any manual editing of the `torrc` by selecting the green onion menu (`Tor Button`), then selecting `Tor Network Settings`. You will be able to select an option to say that a proxy is required for you to access the internet. Once configured Tor Browser will then use the proxy of your choosing to make all of it's connections into the Tor network, anything you use with Tor Browsers SOCKS proxy would then be routed over Tor, via the HTTPS proxy.

As was mentioned by Jens, if you want to route all of your operating systems traffic over Tor, the most simple choice for this would be [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/). Similar to Tor Browser, Tails has a [`Greeter Menu`](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/startup_options/network_configuration/index.en.html), where it is possible to choose any proxy settings that are required. Once you've booted into Tails, you will have access to a user-friendly desktop environment designed around utilising Tor exclusively for network connectivity *(all other traffic is dropped to prevent leaks)* and enabling anonymity.

To answer a request in one of your comments, there is no currently supported or well tested method to route all traffic for a Windows 10 system over the Tor network outside of some kind of "transproxy" enforcing external device or "tor router". These are invariably (thus far) sub-optimal and certainly worse than just using Tor Browser. This is because they don't have any context to isolate "streams", your windows update may end up using exactly the same circuit as your email or web browsing, and thus link your windows installation to other traffic and the host operating system (Windows 10) wasn't designed to improve your privacy or indistinguishability from other users.

Furthermore many applications and protocols were designed with the naive assumption that internet connections cannot be actively tampered with, they are not resistant to an active network adversary and as such aren't fit for purpose anywhere, but certainly not on the Tor network where the exit can make arbitrary changes to your traffic. *(**N.B.** This is not a problem exclusive to Tor, it's applies to everything on the internet)*